# show product price with "incl GST" text after price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tax-class

I have setup my store for Australia. The procedure i followed is this [Setting store for Australia](https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/how-to-set-up-a-magento-store-for-australia)

> According to this : To set tax correctly for Australia (prices shown
>   include GST) and to apply discounts correctly, the following should be
>   set: System → Configuration → Tax Tax Classes
>
> ```
> Tax Class for Shipping = Shipping
> ```
>
> **Calculation Settings**
>
> ```
> Tax Based On = Shipping Address
> Catalog prices include tax = Yes
> Shipping prices include tax = Yes
> Apply Tax After Discount = Yes
> Apply Discount On Prices Including Tax = Yes
> Apply Tax On = Custom price if available
> ```
>
> **Default Tax Destination Calculation**
>
> ```
> Default Country = Australia
> ```
>
> **Display**
>
> ```
> Display Cart/Order Prices = Including tax
> Display full tax summary = No
> Display Shipping Prices = Including tax
> Display Product Prices = Including tax
> ```

But i couldn't get text "incl GST" after price in product detail.

Comment: have you need product price display with incl GST right on details page?

Comment: Yes. Product price display with incl GST on detail page. for eg **$455 incl GST**

Comment: Please Settings in admin side

Price Display Settings

Display Product Prices In Catalog : Including tax

Comment: @Abdul `system > configuration > catalog > ` then i couldn't find `price display setting`, there is `price` toggle menu but there isn't display settings  ??

Comment: system > configuration > sales -> tax  : Price Display Settings

Comment: Yes that was previously as it is `Display Product Prices In Catalog -> Including tax` . i have followed these steps https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/how-to-set-up-a-magento-store-for-australia still couldn't get..

Comment: have you add products with taxable?

Comment: Tax Class * : Taxable Good & None?

Comment: @Abdul Products have `Tax Class` : `Taxable Good`